# Problema con Update en BD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

Tengo un problema con lo mencionado en el título. Cuando quiero actualizar un registro de la base de dato, me aparece `404|Not Found` en la página.

¿Alguien sabe que es? Me aparece como que fuera de ruta pero he hecho de todo y no se recompone, les muestro el código para que puedan ayudarme!

CONTROLLER

```js
    public function edit ($rut_alumno)
    {
        
        $usuario = alumnos::where('rut_alumno',$rut_alumno)->get();
        if (!$usuario) {
            return 'usuario no encontrado';
        }
        return view('Alumnos.alumnos', ['usuario' => $usuario]);
        //return view('Alumnos.alumnos')->with(['usuario'=> $usuario]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $rut_alumno)
    {
        $alum = alumnos::findOrFail($rut_alumno);

            $alum -> nombre = $request -> nombre;
            $alum -> apellido = $request -> apellido;
            $alum -> edad = $request -> edad;
            $alum -> email = $request -> email;
            $alum -> clave = $request -> clave;

    $alumnos->save(); 

    return redirect::to('Alumnos.alumnos')->with('notice', 'Usuario Modificado');
```

```
<form action="/update" method="POST">
                <!-- sistema de seguridad analiza los hacks head, get, options para evitar injection -->
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                <!-- fin -->

                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="RUT (Ej.: 12345678-9)" id="rut">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido" id="apellido">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Edad" id="edad">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" id="clave">
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                <!-- ./ cuerpo pop-up-->
```

les dejo la ruta!

```js
//editar Alumno
Route::get ('/editar', 'AlumnosController@editarAlumno');
Route::post ('/update/{rut_alumno}', 'AlumnosController@update');
```

y una imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe destacar que el formulario está en un modal popup, espero puedan ayudarme por favor! muchas gracias, si alguien conoce alguna forma mejor de pasar esos datos se lo agradeceria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos a replantear todo el código, para que sigas un poco más las convenciones de Laravel.

Primero, las rutas:

Los métodos update() normalmente utilizan el verbo PUT o PATCH, además deberías aprovechar la practicidad de Route Model Binding, para no tener que cargar el modelo en el controlador manualmente, y además, asignarle un nombre a cada ruta:

```
Route::get('editar/{alumno}', 'AlumnosController@edit')->name('alumno.edit');
Route::put('update/{alumno}', 'AlumnosController@update')->name('alumno.update');
```

Veo que no hay una validación de la información del formulario, la cual debería existir, especialmente para el rut.

Para poder acceder al formulario de edición, debería existir un enlace como este, probablemente en un listado de modelos: `<a href="{{ route('alumno.edit', $alumno->rut_alumno) }}">Editar alumno</a>`

---

A continuación, el modelo: El nombre del modelo tampoco sigue las convenciones de Laravel, debería llamarse `Alumno` (Con mayúscula iniciando y en singular). Para que podamos utilizar Route Model Binding y otras funcionalidades, debemos indicarle qué campo es la llave primaria:

```
<?php

// ...

class Alumno extends Model
{
    // ...

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'rut_alumno';

    // ...
}
```

---

A continuación revisamos el controlador, para reflejar Route Model Binding y para aplicar algo de estilo de código PSR-2, también explico un montaje básico del método edit, el cual permite obtener el modelo que se va a editar y pasar los datos necesarios a la vista:

```
public function edit(Alumno $alumno)
{
    return view('alumnos.edit', compact('alumno'));
}
```

Aquí estamos llamando la vista ubicada en views/alumnos/edit.blade.php y que contiene el formulario de edición.

```
public function update(Alumno $alumno, Request $request)
{
    $alumnos->nombre = $request->nombre;
    $alumnos->apellido = $request->apellido;
    $alumnos->edad = $request->edad;
    $alumnos->email = $request->email;
    $alumnos->clave = $request->clave;

    $alumnos->save();

    return redirect::to('Alumnos.alumnos')->with('notice', 'Usuario Modificado');
}
```

---

Por último, en la vista debes realizar esta modificación en el formulario, para que el modelo llegue «automáticamente» en la ruta, sin necesidad de escribirlo en un campo:

```
<form action="{{ route('alumno.update', $alumno->rut_alumno) }}" method="POST">

    @csrf
    @method('PUT')

    .....
```

Es MUY importante que leas la documentación de Laravel, especialmente:

- Eloquent y relaciones: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships
- Rutas: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing

Comment: entiendo super!, el tema que no me esta encontrando la variable de mi input, (para que este se rellene solo) este es el codigo de mi input

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rut" value="{!! $usuario->rut_alumno !!}">

Comment: hay las agrege shaz

Comment: ¿Cómo se accede al método edit? porque veo que no es el mismo método de la ruta.

Comment: ese es mi tema compañero, nose como accedo al metodo, si coloco un form o algo asi, (perdona mi ignorancia)

Comment: ¿eh? no entiendo, ¿cómo llegas acaso al formulario de edición?

Comment: el formulario de edicion es un popUp

Comment: Pero de algún lado debe aparecer el formulario o el popup, lo que sea, esa vista debe estar atada a una ruta.

Comment: no lo tengo con ninguna ruta la forma en que llamo al popUp es en la pagina de esta forma

Comment: data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-editar-alumno"

Comment: Creo que no me estás entendiendo, pero bueno, voy a reorganizar toda la respuesta para explicar los conceptos más básicos de Laravel.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias amigo!

Comment: @MatiasMuñoz ya realicé todas las modificaciones necesarias, en caso que ya no entiendas, tendrás que leer la documentación de Laravel, o remitirte a una lectura de patrones de diseño básicos, como MVC.

Comment: he estado viendo videos y voy adentrarme a la documentacion, muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Dejo por acá: puedes usar en el update la función fill de los modelos $alumno->fill($request->only($alumno->getFillable())); así no hay que colocar cada campo, claro que ésto sería solo cuando quieres modificar todos los campos que se encuentra como fillables en tu modelo :D. Saludos.

Comment: @zerocool sí, pero si lees los comentarios, te darás cuenta que es una explicación de los conceptos más básicos, y es posible que el OP no comprenda muy bien ese método por ahora.

Answer (score 0):

> Tu ruta en el formulario es `action="/update"` pero en tu archivo de rutas es `/update/{rut_alumno}` es decir no son las mismas pues la segunda espera el paso de una variable y la primera no

Ahora renombra tu ruta de este modo

```
Route::post ('/update/{rut_alumno}', 'AlumnosController@update')->name('alumno.update');
```

Después en tu formulario deberías manejar la invocación de la ruta por medio del helper `route` de este modo

```
<form action="{{ route('alumno.update', $alum->rut_alumno) }}" method="POST">
```

En la línea anterior:

- Al helper le pasamos como primer argumento el nombre que le dimos a la ruta `alumno.update`
- Posterior como segundo argumento le indicamos `$alum` que acceda a la propiedad `rut_alumno` pues es con esta misma que estas filtrando y encontrando al usuario que vas a actualizar.

Además de lo anterior, estas tratando de hacer un query por una columna que no es el `id` por lo que deberás hacer una sobreescritura en tu Modelo para indicar el nombre de dicha columna, de este modo

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'rut_alumno';
}
```

- Aquí mas sobre [`rutas nombradas` en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)
- Aquí ve a [`customizing the key name`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing) para saber mas sobre el último punto que menciono

Comment: Gracias por tomar tu tiempo y responder mi pregunta, ultimamente he estado con mucho trabajo y por fin pude retomar mi proyecto, hice lo que me mencionaste pero ahora me sale un problema de variable "Undefined variable: alum" en el "FORM" :( gracias amigo!

Comment: si tengo el metodo edit, el tema es que no lo he invocado en ninguna parte :c

Comment: Aaaa, ahora lo entiendo mucho mejor, y no, no lo tengo asi

Comment: el metodo edit lo invoco en el boton "editar"?

Comment: entiendo, lo tengo asi mira (lo cambie) <a href="{!! route('Alumnos.editarAlumno', $alumn->rut_alumno) !!}" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>

Comment: public function editarAlumno (Request $request, $rut_alumno)
    {
        $alumn = alumnos::all();
        $alumn = alumnos::findOrFail($rut_alumno);
        return view('Alumnos.alumnos', ['alumn' => $alumn, 'alumn' => $alumn]);
        return view('Alumnos.alumnos', compact('alumnos'));
    }